# Python 3, NetworkX - Graph node key list is not displaying repeated edges

Tags: python, graph, python-3.x, networkx

I'm using the NetworkX module on Python 3.2.3. In a multigraph G with multiple edges between two nodes - say, 'a' and 'b' with three edges between them - typing G['a'].keys() into the IDLE prompt returns a dict_keys list with 'b' occurring only once in it. Any way to make it so that 'b' occurs as many times as there are edges between the two nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
[(k, len(v)) for k, v in G['a'].items()]
```

Comment: Helped a lot, thanks very much! That problem was screwing up my implementation of the solution to the MinCut problem.

Answer (score 1):

The NetworkX API suggests you use G.neighbors(), but for multigraphs that will only give the unique neighbors.

If you want all neighbors you can use [v for u,v in G.edges_iter()], e.g.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G=nx.MultiGraph()

In [3]: G.add_edge('a','b')

In [4]: G.add_edge('a','b')

In [5]: G.add_edge('a','b')

In [6]: [v for u,v in G.edges_iter()]
Out[6]: ['b', 'b', 'b']
```